# sysprocesses table inside or outside a sql server agent job is not the same

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent

I try to write a simple sql server agent job to run daily. The sql statement is as follows:

insert into testtable (nt_username, last_batch)
select nt_username, last_batch from master.sys.sysprocesses where nt_username <> ''

The same sql statement works great if I run it in management studio. But it only returns one record something like:

Administrator 2016-07-14 13:07:08.270

when it runs as a sql server agent job. As a result, it is useless. What did I do wrong and how to fix it? What is the correct sql statement for the same result that works as a sql agent job? My sql server is sql 2008 R2 with service pack 2 (10.50.4000) running on windows server 2008.

Thanks.

Comment: The record returned is because of your session.  What user owns the job?  I assume it's a SQL login and not a domain account which explains why there is no nt_username and an overall empty result set (since you said the query ran from SSMS only returns 1 record).

Comment: Thanks for the message. But it does not matter which account that I use. I tried system admin account, sql system admin account and a few other accounts. The result is always the same. By the way, this used to work well in sql 2000.

Comment: @GeorgeFang SQL Server 2000 was quite a bit different. It provided far less info to us, and had less granular permissions. Please see the update at the end of my answer for the part that you were missing.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use `sysprocesses`. It was deprecated when SQL Server 2005 was released, and the `sys.sysprocesses` "table" you are using is just a compatibility view. The MSDN page for [sys.sysprocesses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881.aspx) even has a note at the top stating:

> This SQL Server 2000 system table is included as a view for backward compatibility. We recommend that you use the current SQL Server system views instead. To find the equivalent system view or views, see [Mapping System Tables to System Views (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187997.aspx). This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

You should instead use the new DMV (Dynamic Management Views):

- [sys.dm_exec_sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx)
- [sys.dm_exec_requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx)
- [sys.dm_exec_connections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx)

Please note that a Login might need to be granted the server-level permission of `VIEW SERVER STATE` in order to see more than their own data for `sys.dm_exec_sessions` and `sys.dm_exec_requests`, or see anything at all in `sys.dm_exec_connections`.

If this permission is needed, then the current database when you run the `GRANT` statement needs to be `master` as this is a server-level permission.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your suggestion with no success. The result is always the same.

Comment: @GeorgeFang What exact query are you running?

Comment: As an example, I tried the following sql query:
insert into testtable (nt_username, last_batch)
select nt_user_name, login_time from master.sys.dm_exec_sessions where nt_user_name <> ''

with no success

Comment: @GeorgeFang Ok. And did you see my update regarding the required permission of `VIEW SERVER STATE`?

Comment: Why is there such a complexity? Could you post the statement to grant view server state to somebody somehow to get this sql server agent job to work properly? By the way, the job is run under dbo or sql system administrator account. So there should not be any permission restrictions here. It simple does not work for me regardless what id I use to run the job.

Comment: @GeorgeFang It should just be: `USE [master];
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT];` just replace the name if different from your service account. Also, what do you mean that the job is "run under dbo or sql sys admin"? `dbo` isn't a login; it's a user which is database-level. The issue here is server level and so relates to Logins. Are you speaking of the `run as user` on the "Advanced" tab?

Comment: Ok, I run the command and it still does not help. Regardless, I am the administrator for the system and the sql server and all that. So I can have all the permissions I want. But I cannot get this sql server agent job to work properly after I run your sql command successfully. What did I do wrong? By the way, you are also right on the dbo part. That is what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

After some careful examination, it turns out the culprit is that the sql server agent process must be run under a domain account. I encountered the problem because it run under network service account. The weird part is the sql server also runs under the same network service account with no problems. What a headache this is especially when you are in a hurry to just get a thing to work.

Comment: This is not true. You just needed to grant that network service account the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission. Please see my answer for details.

Comment: Also, the fact that the SQL Server service also runs as that same network service account is not relevant because when you log into SQL Server, the security context is _you_, not the network service account. Yet when SQL Agent logs into SQL Server, the security context is of that network service account. Unless you set up a proxy account to use for the SQL Agent jobs.